# switching from French to Arabic in JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a form which contains JTextFields, some are specific for French and others for Arabic.
i want to switch from a language to another without pressing alt+shift key.
any help on the solution will be appreciated. thanks,

Comment: don't quite understand the question, so a blind shoot: myTextField.setLocale(...)? Or is it about how to assign that action to a keyStroke? If so, have a look at KeyBindings (in the tutorial referenced in the swing tag)

Comment: I want to set a Locale of a Jtextfield and i use this code but it doesn't work: //                                               private void issmMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                                   Locale l = new Locale("ar");
mytextfield.setLocale(l);
mytextfield.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks aymeric for your answer, but i found a solution for the problem, here is how i resolve the problem:

```
public void Arabe(JTextField txt) {
    txt.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ar", "SA"));
    txt.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);    
}

public void Français(JTextField txt) {
    txt.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("fr","FR"));
    txt.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);    
}

private void txt1_FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                     
    Arabe(my_textfields1);
}                                    

private void txt2_FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                        
    Français(mytextfields2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the question is that you want some specific textfields to be in Arabic (from right to left + with arabic characters) and some other in French.

If your main concern is to avoid the user to press ALT+SHIT, just make your program do it for him :)

This is only a example to get you started (if you didn't find any solution yet):

```
public class Test {

    /** 
     * This method will change the keyboard layout so that if the user has 2 languages
     * installed on his computer, it will switch between the 2 
     * (tested with french and english) 
     */
    private static void changeLang() {
        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        JTextField arabicTextField = new JTextField();
        JTextField frenchTextField = new JTextField();

        f.add(frenchTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(arabicTextField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frenchTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                changeLang();
            }
        });

        arabicTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                changeLang();
            }
        });

        arabicTextField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```