# use multi languages in swing application

Tags: java, swing

We can use several font styles in a swing application and can assign different font style for different swing text fields. But is there any way to configure one JTextField in java swing application to support multi languages. For example input is address.

> 12B "street name in other language"

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("example",30);
Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,12);
field.setFont(font);
```

How can we achieve this? is there any font that support dual font style (English + French).

**UPDATE AFTER FIRST ANSWER**

Also need to send typed text into database and retrieve back with same format. So I think it is not possible to switch between font dynamically.

**UPDATE 2**

If we consider Microsoft word we can use multiple fonts in a single page. So there should be a algorithm to save typed letters with respective font. how can we make this kind of behavior in swing without making two text fields for different language inputs.

[image]

Comment: What are you actually looking for? A font that has the necessary characters can display both. Fonts that have good extended latin support are common (you might have problems if you want characters from completely different character set).

Comment: In my application i am using Unicode font. In the above case it changes B into Unicode character. it is obvious behavior of that font. I searched dual language fonts. i couldn't find any references.

Comment: I suppose you can build your own text field that is built up from multiple `JTextField`s, each with different language. Take away the individual borders and you have your own, customizable, multi language display field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mix fonts by using HTML tags if you change the component to a `JTextPane`. The code below will create a field containing the text "Hello world" with font Times New Roman for "Hello" and Courier for "World!":

```
JTextPane field = new JTextPane();
field.setContentType("text/html");
field.setText("<html><font face=\"Times New Roman\">Hello</font> <font face=\"Courier\">world!</font></html>");
```

Here is a runnable example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MultiFontField text = new MultiFontField();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    text.appendText("Hello ", "Times New Roman").appendText("world!", "Courier").finaliseText();

    frame.add(text);
    frame.setSize(200, 50);     
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is the `MultiFontField` class:

```
public class MultiFontField extends JTextPane {

    private StringBuilder content;

    public MultiFontField() {
        super();
        this.content = new StringBuilder("<html>");
        this.setContentType("text/html");
    }

    public MultiFontField appendText(String text, String font) {
        content.append("<font face=\"").append(font).append("\">").append(text).append("</font>");
        return this;
    }

    public void finaliseText() {
        this.setText(content.append("</html>").toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the locale of the text field, as per your need. You can check the answer provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926360/switching-from-french-to-arabic-in-jtextfields).

Comment: updated little bit. sry for the update. i got idea after your answer